# How to call a function in postgres

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports

I have a function in Jaspersoft by which I am calling it to postgres 
the function is as:

```
SELECT * FROM getethnicityanalysisreportdata($P{site_name}) where  $X{IN, sitename}
```

And now I am using:

```
select getethnicityanalysisreportdata("site_name");
```

in postgres for testing.
But It is not working.
Can anyone help me ??

Comment: "it is not working". The error message is....?

Comment: error : "site_name" does not exist

Comment: Unless maybe you're on a really ancient PostgreSQL version that's not the full error message. Please always show the full, exact error message. But anyway, it's enough for me to notice what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should call to function in the following way:

```
select "getethnicityanalysisreportdata"('site_name');
```

Put your function name in double quotes. It will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

SQL literals are single-quoted. SQL identifiers are double-quoted.

There is no column or table named `site_name`, hence the error, which was actually:

```
regress=>  select getethnicityanalysisreportdata("site_name");
ERROR:  column "site_name" does not exist
LINE 1: select getethnicityanalysisreportdata("site_name");
```

You should use single quotes if you want a literal string:

```
select getethnicityanalysisreportdata('site_name');
```

See [the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html).